# Android Emulator with Qemu VNC, mouse & keyboard not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, vnc-server

I am running an android emulator and connecting to it via VNC, but the mouse and keyboard is not reacting.

`./emulator64-x86 -avd test2 -no-audio -no-window -qemu -enable-kvm -vnc :14`

I am able to see the VNC display but my mouse and keyboard does not work with the VNC session.